# Infimum over area of certain convex polygons

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Let us identify the Euclidean plane with the complex plane $\Bbb C$.

For every $n\ge 1$,  consider the following collection of finite sets in $\Bbb C^{n+1}$:
$$S_n:=\{(z_0,z_1,\dots,z_n)\in\Bbb C^{n+1} : |z_i-z_j|\ge 2,~\forall i\ne j~\},$$
and for every $v=(z_0,z_1,\dots,z_n)\in S_n$, define
$$P(v)=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z-z_0|\le |z-z_i|,~i=1,\dots, n\}.$$
By definition, $P(v)$ is the intersection of finitely many closed half-planes, so its area, denoted by $|P(v)|$, is either $+\infty$(when $P(v)$ is unbounded) or a well defined finite number(when $P(v)$ is bounded, i.e. a convex polygon).

My question is:

> $$I:=\inf_{n\ge 1}\inf_{v\in S_n}|P(v)|=~?$$

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Remark:**

1. $P((z_0,\dots,z_n))$ always contains the closed disk centered at $z_0$ with of radius $1$, so $I\ge \pi$. This lower bound $I$ can be easily improved using simple methods with tedious calculation, but the methods in my mind are not good enough to give a precise estimate of $I$.
2. Let $v=(0,z_1,\dots,z_6)\in S_6$, where $z_k=2e^{\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{3}k\pi}$, $1\le k\le6$. Note that $z_1,\dots,z_6$ are vertices of a regular hexagon centered at $0$ and $P(v)$ is the regular hexagon centered at $0$ with vertices $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}e^{\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{6}(2k+1)\pi}$, $1\le k\le6$, so $I\le|P(v)|=2\sqrt{3}$. I am totally clueless whether $I=2\sqrt{3}$ or not.
3. My question arises from reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528749/53845).

Comment: This could simply be worded as: "What is the smallest Voronoi cell that can be produced by a set of points in the plane, no two of which are closer than $2$ units apart?"

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Thank you. I never heard the concept of Voronoi cell/polygon before. Do you know if there is any known result about Voronoi cell which solves my problem directly?

Comment: This ought to be a step in the proof that the densest circle packing is hexagonal. I would try references [2] and [10] from [this paper](http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/pages/faculty/lenny/papers/hexagon.pdf)

Comment: @user103402: Thank you for your references. I doubt if I can find the answer of my problem out from the references directly. Because I have no pretty much time to spend on this problem, I will wait for an answer from others than myself first.

Comment: As far as I remember, the regular hexagon is the worst scenario. The proof is somewhat ugly and basically boils down to showing that the area in the corner bounded by the perpendiculars to 2 adjacent sides is at least a certain constant times the angle (you should be very careful because the perpendicular may fail to meet the side but cross some other side instead). If you really need it for something, I'll try to recall and post the details. Otherwise, I'll just stop here.

Comment: @fedja: Thank you for your comment. I ask this question just for curiosity, and my curiosity was caused by an attempt to answer the linked question and by some confusion of the answer in the linked question(I explained my confusion in a comment of that answer, but I haven't been replied yet). Therefore, please don't be bothered by posting an answer.

Comment: @fedja: Some questions about your comment. By saying  "perpendiculars", do you mean  perpendicular bisectors of the sides? If so, how could some perpendicular bisector fail to meet the corresponding side? I believe that the area is bounded from below by a certain constant times the angle, but I cannot see how this could lead to whole solution of the problem(if it's not easy to explain in a few words, please just ignore it).

Comment: No. I mean the line from the center of the cell perpendicular to the line containing the side. If the constant is what it should be (i.e., the one for the hexagon), then you just add the inequalities and use the fact that the full angle is $2\pi$. Of course, the hustle is to get the sharp value, not just something.

Comment: @fedja: Sorry, actually I understood your meaning of "perpendicular" correctly, but I expressed my understanding incorrectly. You argument seems work, at least it works for the special case below. Let me denote the quadrilateral by $ABCD$, where $A$ is the center of the cell. Suppose $\angle CAB=\angle CAD :=\theta$. Then the ratio between the area of $ABCD$ and the angle $\angle BAD$ is $\max\{\frac{\tan \theta}{\theta},\frac{1}{2\theta\sin 2\theta}\}$, which attains its minimum at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$, coinciding with the regular hexagon case.

Comment: @fedja: I forgot to mention that I can see why "the perpendicular may fail to meet the side but cross some other side instead" now. Thank you very much for your helpful comments, which convinces me of $I=2\sqrt{3}$. (However, I am trying to use your approach to completely solve the problem by myself at this moment, because this approach seems a little complicated in details to me.)